# MATLAB Mex-file error: Afx.h not found

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I wrote a MATLAB code that uses mex-file with a computer that uses windows 32bits, and this code worked. Then, I imported this code on an other computer that uses windows 64bits (I'm still building this code with Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 - C++) and I have the following error: C:\users\documents\matlab\StdAfx.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Afx.h': No such file or directory

When I comment the line "#include "StdAfx.h" in the C++ file I call from MATLAB, I have the following error log:

```
>> readTest
Building with 'Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 (C++)'.
Error using mex
Test704.cpp
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'EXPORT'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'PortRead'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier -
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier -
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'EXPORT'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C2182: 'WINAPI' : illegal use of
type 'void'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C2371: 'WINAPI' : redefinition;
different basic types
        c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : see declaration of 'WINAPI'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'PortWrite'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C4430: missing type specifier -
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C2086: 'int EXPORT' : redefinition
        c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(6) : see declaration of 'EXPORT'
c:\users\icm\documents\matlab\704IO.h(7) : error C4430: missing type specifier -
int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(14) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'theApp'
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(14) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(42) : warning C4244: 'argument' :
conversion from 'double' to 'short', possible loss of data
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(42) : warning C4244: 'argument' :
conversion from 'double' to 'short', possible loss of data
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(42) : warning C4244: 'argument' :
conversion from 'double' to 'short', possible loss of data
C:\Users\ICM\Documents\MATLAB\Test704.cpp(53) : warning C4244: 'return' :
conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

And here is the code behind the "704IO.h" file:

```
// 704IO.h : export header file for the 704IO DLL
//

#pragma once

extern "C" short WINAPI EXPORT PortRead(short Rack, short Port, short Offset);
extern "C" void WINAPI EXPORT PortWrite(short Rack, short Port, short Offset, short Value);
```

I made some researches about my issues, and I think it could be a compatibility error, but I cannot find how to solve it, do you have any idea?

Comment: What's on the first lines of 704.h that are causing the blow up? Could you post lines 1-7? It could be some non-standard c++ that the more modern compiler won't let fly anymore?

Comment: I'd check that your specific compiler is supported by your specific version of Matlab. Also, the error you mention, "C:\users\documents\matlab\StdAfx.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Afx.h': No such file or directory" isn't in the log you listed?

Comment: Here is all that the 704IO.h fil contains (line 1 to 7):  <br/>// 704IO.h : export header file for the 704IO DLL  <br/>
//  <br/>

#pragma once  <br/>

extern "C" short WINAPI EXPORT PortRead(short Rack, short Port, short Offset);  <br/>
extern "C" void WINAPI EXPORT PortWrite(short Rack, short Port, short Offset, short Value);  <br/>

Comment: (1) You should put that piece of 704IO.h in the question. (2) #pragma denotes a compiler directive, and compiler directives may be *specific to a particular compiler*! My guess is that the code has a directive that's not understood by the new compiler but was understood by the old compiler.

Comment: My mistake, I edited my question about the fact that "C:\users\documents\matlab\StdAfx.h(19): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Afx.h': No such file or directory" isn't in the error log and added the code of 704IO.h. So do you think I should change my C++ compiler or shall I simply comment the "#pragma once" line ?

Comment: looks like you need to define WINAPI? You can do so by including windows.h or do something like `#define WINAPI  __stdcall”`. Unless it's EXPORT which is not defined?

Comment: #pragma once should be fine. I thought the #pragma line was huge, lol. Looks like an issue with Visual Studio created header "Afx.h" and various windows api stuff... I've been on linux and Mac for so long I'm probably no help on this.

Comment: @ManaV you should be able to comment out the Afx.h but you will probably need to replace by "include <windows.h>"...

Comment: @gregswiss I tried to replace #include "StdAfx.h" by #include "windows.h" but I still have the same error

Comment: @matthewGunn I tried to change of compiler and I still have the same errors.